# can wget limit number of retrieved pages / links in recursive / spider mode?

Tags: wget

i use wget for either:

- retrieving some sites recursively,
- spider (retrieve links from websites)

Sometimes i'd like to get only a certain arbitrary maximum of pages / links.

The only limits I've found in wget so far are:

- volume (Mb/Kb etc.)
- directory recursion level
- download rate

is it possible to limit downloaded link count?